# Select last 3 rows from database order by id ASC OOP PHP

Tags: php, database, oop, pdo

```
SELECT FROM users.id,username ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 3
```

Not working in output,
this line not error showing
how to correct line ?

Comment: SELECT what ??????

Comment: just 3 row on user_id

Comment: Did you tested this query as you wrote it ? Does it get any errors ?

Comment: USe it as `SELECT COLUMN1 ,COLUMN2 ,COLUMN3 FROM ....`

Comment: Your `SELECT` syntax is completely wrong.  You have the columns in the `FROM` clause, and you don't have any tables.  There ***is*** an error, you're just ignoring it.

Comment: i need 3 user for Suggestions to follow after that

Comment: didn't grasp the right tutorials I see

Answer (score 1):

You would be better served writing the following...

```
SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 3
```

Your original query is wrong, SQL, like any programming language, needs to be written EXACTLY as intended.

Please do an introductory course on SQL.

Comment: is SQL a **programming language** ? OR **Non Procedural Language**

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
SELECT id, username FROM users ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: then 
on file db 
i limit row 
$sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ($placeIds) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1";

Comment: @DevKurd: Your code is wide open to SQL injection.  The syntax you're using may be broken, but other users can just execute whatever correctly formed (and malicious) code they want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!